Qemu returning repetitive messages for custom bootloader
I am writing a bootloader for an OS and after a bit of debugging I have found the place where it hangs. The OS is simple and uses 16 bit real mode(although if the only way to fix this is switching to protected mode I will do it).
; Load the second stage
mov ah, 0x02                    ; BIOS read function
mov al, 2                       ; Number of sectors to read
mov ch, 0                       ; Cylinder 0
mov cl, 2                       ; Sector 2 (1-indexed)
mov dh, 0                       ; Head 0
mov dl, [0x7C1E]                ; Drive number
mov bx, SECOND_STAGE_ADDRESS    ; Where to load the second stage

int 0x13                        ; BIOS interrupt to read sectors
jc error                        ; If carry flag was set, there was an error


the main errors are

It repetitively updates CR0 to 0x00000010 and then to 0x00000011
After a while it just starts doing check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0x6 forever

debug log:
debug
source code
text
makefile:
# File paths
BOOTLOADER_SRC = first_stage.asm
SECOND_STAGE_SRC = second_stage.asm
KERNEL_SRC = kernel.c
OS_IMAGE = os_image.bin
BOOTLOADER_BIN = first_stage.bin
SECOND_STAGE_BIN = second_stage.bin
KERNEL_BIN = kernel.bin
QEMU_LOG = qemu-debug.log

# Targets
all: os_image

os_image: $(BOOTLOADER_BIN) $(SECOND_STAGE_BIN) $(KERNEL_BIN)
    @echo "Creating disk image..."
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(OS_IMAGE) bs=512 count=2880
    dd if=$(BOOTLOADER_BIN) of=$(OS_IMAGE) conv=notrunc
    dd if=$(SECOND_STAGE_BIN) of=$(OS_IMAGE) seek=1 conv=notrunc
    dd if=$(KERNEL_BIN) of=$(OS_IMAGE) seek=3 conv=notrunc

run: os_image
    @echo "Running QEMU..."
    qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=$(OS_IMAGE),index=0,media=disk -d int,cpu_reset,mmu -D $(QEMU_LOG)

debug: os_image
    @echo "Running QEMU with debugging..."
    qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=$(OS_IMAGE),index=0,media=disk -s -S -d int,cpu_reset,mmu -D $(QEMU_LOG)

clean:
    rm -f $(BOOTLOADER_BIN) $(SECOND_STAGE_BIN) $(KERNEL_BIN) $(OS_IMAGE) $(QEMU_LOG)

# Build the bootloader, second stage, and kernel
$(BOOTLOADER_BIN): $(BOOTLOADER_SRC)
    nasm -f bin -o $@ $<

$(SECOND_STAGE_BIN): $(SECOND_STAGE_SRC)
    nasm -f bin -o $@ $<

$(KERNEL_BIN): $(KERNEL_SRC)
    i386-elf-gcc -m16 -ffreestanding -c $(KERNEL_SRC) -o kernel.o
    i386-elf-ld -Ttext 0x1000 --oformat binary kernel.o -o $(KERNEL_BIN)

.PHONY: all run debug clean


I tried adding debug code, which is how I found where the error is, I made qemu make a debug log, which is how I found what the error is.

Using 0x7C1E makes no sense. That is overwriting your own code. Apart from that it works here. Make sure the error is not in your second stage.

The error is not in my second stage as it outputs the debug message before the piece of code I put in the text but doesn't output the debug message after.

also what address do you recommend to store dl in?

Allocate a byte variable somewhere and let the assembler figure the proper address. E.g. put a drive: db 0 somewhere not inside the execution path. Or use push/pop.

so I should just write drive db 0 somewhere? I have two parts in two different files, how can I make sure they each recognize what drive means?

You can allocate address by hand if you wish but make sure it does not overlap your code. For example, you could use the next 512 bytes at 0x7e00 for data and load the second stage after that. You can also use a linker.

OK I did that in my first stage and now it goes through loading the second stage. After doing a 0x13 interrupt the carry flag is set though and it goes into my error script.
